# How do I add a code snippet with a number as a tabstop

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Consider the following [JSON schema snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_define-snippets-in-json-schemas):

```js
{
    "label": "New spell",
    "description": "Creates a new spell",
    "body": {
        "name": "$1",
        "source": "$2",
        "page": "${3}",
        "tradition": "$4",
        "type": "${5|U,A|}",
        "level": "${6}",
        "description": ["$7"]
    }
}
```

Both `page` and `level` need to be an integer (can default to `0`), but also be a [tabstop](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_tabstops). I have tried a few things, but the only value that acts as a tabstop is enclosed in quotes, so it ends up being a string.
Is there a way to add a tabstop where the default value is a number?

Comment: Found the answer, will post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

This would work to set a tabstop 3 and 6 with defaults of 0.  Note that the quotes must be escaped.

```
"\"page\": \"${3:0}\""
```

Also the general form of a snippet is as follows:

```
"new spell": {
    "description": "Creates a new spell",
    // "scope": "javascript,typescript",

    "prefix": "new spell",       // whatever prefix you want

    "body": [                      // array
        "\"page\": \"${3:0}\"",
        "\"level\": \"${6:0}\"",
    ]
}
```

There is no `label` property and there should be a `prefix` property.  And `body`, if multiple statements is an array.

Comment: Ah, my bad, these are not general snippets, but rather [schema-specific snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_define-snippets-in-json-schemas). I will update the question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_define-snippets-in-json-schemas):

> If a string starts with ^, the string content will be inserted as-is, not stringified. You can use this to specify snippets for numbers and booleans.

The value string needs to be specified as `"^${3:0}"`.

So, the snippet fixed:

```js
{
    "label": "New spell",
    "description": "Creates a new spell",
    "body": {
        "name": "$1",
        "source": "$2",
        "page": "^${3:0}",
        "tradition": "$4",
        "type": "${5|U,A|}",
        "level": "^${6:0}",
        "description": ["$7"]
    }
}
```